# Adding Qur'an & Hadith program to the site

Tags: discussion, support

I want to call for an attention on maybe this site should include Qur'an and Hadith program that may help may people from going to order site and bring reference.

I think this will decrease the issue of copy and paste questions and answers

Comment: This is not a feasible request within a beta site. And even if it were so this should be addressed on the [stackexchange Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com) site not in a beta site's Meta.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a feasible request within a beta site. And even if it were so this should be addressed on the [stackexchange Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com) site not in a beta site's Meta. Be aware that IMHO your request is only feasible on a totally independent site.

I don't see any major improvement in having such programs or apps on the site.
There are good and credible resources for qur'an, qur'an and hadith translations on the internet and referring to such resources actually is rather wanted as a good answer includes references to (different or external) sources. Else we would need to justify the authenticity of our program's sources and data.